# Outlook 2013 does not take subject from mailto link

Tags: outlook, mailto

Our program generates a simple mailto link like the following one:

```
mailto:bernd@bernd.de?&subject=dolphin&body=bla
```

When we open this link or I paste it into any browser, Outlook 2013 does start and fill out the recipient and body, **but the subject always stays empty**, no matter what subject I pass. I don't seem to be the only one with this issue in the company.

I'm not quite sure if this is an Outlook setting issue or a malformed link, that's why I'm asking here first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be due to the use of `&` behind the `?`

I do not have Outlook at hand to test, but would you mind trying:

```
mailto:bernd@bernd.de?subject=dolphin&body=bla
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right. We messed that up. Funny enough, in our tests `mailto:bernd@bernd.de&subject=dolphin&body=bla` also worked (with an ampersand for the first parameter instead of a question mark).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [mailto Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767737(v=vs.85).aspx) page in MSDN which describes possible arguments and string format in depth.

You need to use the following string instead:

```
mailto:bernd@bernd.de?subject=dolphin&body=bla
```